# Run a root script using Magisk mount space

Tags: root-access, shell, magisk

There are many questions on this site about running a root script but none using Magisk mount space.

I have a Pixel 6a and came across [this post (65)](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/mod-pixel-tensor-audio-decompressor.4610051/post-88813837)  in a thread dedicated to improve the speaker output. The developer posted a Magisk module which works fine but the post linked appears to be an improvement since one can vary the output on the fly. That's the reason I want to try that but I don't understand a thing about Magisk mount space and how to use that to run boot scripts.

I tried using Magisk Manager and Fox Manager but was unsuccessful as I expected it to be since it's not a Magisk module. On extracting the zip file, you get a shell script and a template having mixer configurations.

While I asked the poster on how to go about it and am yet to get a reply I believe I can get better answers here.

So, how do I run it? Please be detailed in your answer as I am
not at all conversant with this.

Unsuccessful attempts:

- Set mount name space mode to "Global" in Magisk settings.
- Imported the script in three kernel managers, rebooted, no output.
- Repeated step above with `su - mm` in the first line of script. No luck
- Imported zip file contents to Termux downloads, made them executable and ran `~/downloads $ su -mm && Audio_Mixer_Changer.sh` no output